# Printing number using recursion in java without its biggest digit

Tags: java, recursion

Using recursion I need to input a number and the console will print this number without its highest digit. If it's smaller than 10 it will return 0.

I already found the biggest digit but how can i remove it and print the number without it after?
This is the code for the biggest digit:

```
public static int remLastDigit(int n){

        if(n==0)                              
            return 0;
        return Math.max(n%10, remLastDigit(n/10)); 

    }
```

If i input 12345 i expect the output to be 1234. if i input 9 or less i expect the output to be 0.

Comment: `If it's smaller than 10` means `n<10`

Comment: Input will be a number or numbers ? because using recursion you can take multiple inputs.

Comment: Only one number. For example 6342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
// call this method
public static int removeLastDigit(int number) {
    return removeLastDigitImpl(number, largestDigit(number));
}

private static int removeLastDigitImpl(int number, int largestDigit) {
    if (number < 10) { // if the number is a single digit, decide what to do with it
        if (number == largestDigit) {
            return 0; // if it is the largest digit, remove it
        } else {
            return number; // if it is not, keep it
        }
    }
    // handle the last digit of the number otherwise
    if (number % 10 == largestDigit) {
        // removing the digit
        return removeLastDigitImpl(number / 10, largestDigit);
    } else {
        // not removing the digit
        return removeLastDigitImpl(number / 10, largestDigit) * 10 + number % 10;
    }
}

// this is the same as your attempt
private static int largestDigit(int n){

    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    return Math.max(n%10, largestDigit(n/10));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already found the max digit nicely, here's how you can print the number without it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printWithoutDigit(2349345, remLastDigit(2349345));
    }

    public static void printWithoutDigit(int number, int maxDigit) {
        Integer.toString(number).chars().filter(digit -> Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf((char)digit))!=maxDigit).forEach(d -> System.out.print((char)d));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your number to a String, or more precisely to a char-array. Then, you can find out where in this array the biggest digit is, remove it and convert your char-array back to an integer.

This would roughly look like this:

```
int num = 12345; //the number from which you want to remove the biggest digit
char[] numC = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
int biggestDigit = 0;
int biggestDigitIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numC.length; i++) {
    if (biggestDigit < Character.getNumericValue(numC[i])) {
        biggestDigit = Character.getNumericValue(numC[i]);
        biggestDigitIndex = i;
    }
    //Remove digit at index biggestDigitIndex from numC
    //Convert numC back to int
}
```

Of course, you have to incorporate this into your recursion, which means returning the number you got after converting numC back to int and then feed this into your input parameter again. Also, of course you need to add a check if your number is < 9 in the beginning.